# How to change vuetify "append-outer-icon" size?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I Could not find a way to change the icon size when it is inserted as "append-outer-icon"

```html
<div>
    <v-col
        cols="12"
    >
        <v-text-field
            class="mx-8"
            v-model="message4"
            label="Outlined"
            outlined
            clearable
            append-outer-icon="mdi-plus-circle-outline large"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </div>
```

[image: scrennshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is with CSS. The icon's size is set by [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size):

```css
.v-input__icon.v-input__icon--append-outer i {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWOOKwW)

Answer (score 1):

You can use slot for that icon, check documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#events
append-outer slot is what you need, you can pass v-icon into it and change size of icon by prop described in v-icon documentation.